# Client based solution for upload entire folders to an Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, upload, applet

Im currently writing a web application, where a user should be able to select an folder and upload all of its content to an servlet.
The idea is, that a user can select a folder, the folder and its content will be sent due a post request to the servlet. The servlet takes them, parses the structure and saves the structure in a database. (Filenames , foldernames..etc) (Thats also why, i cannot pass the files directly to the ftp server).
Afterward the servlets connects to an FTP Server, where the files will be stored permanently.
The Web Application uses JavaEE (Apache Tomcat 7.0, Servlet 3.0 API)
Currently Im using JUpload to achieve this, but in fact I've read that it is highly advised against using Java Applets, because of security issues. Also JUpload is not intended to use with Servlet 3.0 API, but with a little hack it works. 
A normal input file form is not sufficient for this need.
Now I'm wondering, because i didnt find any other solution, which can achieve this. I've heard about some Flash Solutions, but im not familiar with flash. And also Flash has some security issues, like Applets.

Is there any other solution to solve this ?

Comment: *" I've read that it is highly advised against using Java Applets, as they are deprecated."*  No they're not.  They suffer from the same horrendous problems they always did, but are not deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i'll remove this term of my question

Comment: What security issues exactly are you referring to? Aren't you just making this up? Aren't you overgeneralizing the problems caused by bad/unsigned applets into good and well developed applets?

Comment: I refer to security issues, not from a programmers point of view. Im not such experienced in this field, but actually I mean from the customer point of view. Some admin of companies just deactivate Java in their Browsers, to avoid such issues.

Comment: Although its not the best solution to overcome this, many comapnies still do. Then also some slighlty older java versions gets automatically deactivated by Browsers, in case of possible exploit vulnerabalities. We cannot force our customers to have the latest java version installed. Also the update rate of oracle doesnt seem to be very high.When i read some other threads here, i got the feeling, that using java applets is not recommended by many. Would you recommend, using Java Applets if there are another techniques, which can solve this ?